# Webview Flutter Cannot Change URL

Tags: flutter, webview

I use the flutter plugin
https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter

I have a webview page like this, when I change the url, the webview still shows the old url, please help

this is my widget main_page.dart

```
Scaffold(
body: 
      selectedMenu == Menu.home ?
      Center(
                      child: WebViewPage(
                      targetUrl: homeUrl,
                    ))
      : selectedMenu == Menu.store ?
      Center(
                      child: WebViewPage(
                      targetUrl: storeUrl,
                    ))
```

this is my widget webview_page.dart

```
class WebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final targetUrl;
  const WebViewPage({
    Key key,
    this.targetUrl,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WebViewPageState createState() => _WebViewPageState();
}

class _WebViewPageState extends State<WebViewPage> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebView(
      initialUrl: widget.targetUrl,
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
        _controller.complete(webViewController);
      },
      onProgress: (int progress) {
        print("WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)");
      },
      onPageStarted: (String url) {
        print('Page started loading: $url');
      },
      onPageFinished: (String url) {
        print('Page finished loading: $url');
      },
      // gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where and how are you changing the webview's url?

Comment: i use paramater targetUrl

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this? I'm seeing the same issue.